# Use speech recognition for data entry

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

I have this from

[image]

I want to use speech recognition for data entry
so for example:
if I say "Item" :I want to set Focus on combobox item and wait me to chose from the list and the same thing for other controls.

this my code:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    private void TestPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "Item", "Quantity", "Date"});
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
    }
    private void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == "Item")
        {
            cmbItem.Focus();
            // I want to chose one item from a list using voice command

        }
        else if(e.Result.Text == "Quantity")
        {
            txtQuantity.Focus();
            // I Want to set the quantity for example 25
        }
        else if (e.Result.Text == "Date")
        {
            txtDate.Focus();
            //I Want to set the date
        }
    }

    private void btnActiveVoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        btnActiveVoice.Enabled = false;
        btnDisableVoice.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnDisableVoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        btnActiveVoice.Enabled = true;
        btnDisableVoice.Enabled = false;
    }
```

this is as far as i can go.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have update my question

Comment: Ok... and is your code working? And if not, what is not working? And what exactly do you want to know? There are three comments in your code which have nothing to do with speech recognition... Please reade the How to I've linked to and afterwards state a clear question and show only the part of the code which is needed to give you an anwser.